# Constrained np.polyfit

Tags: numpy, constraints

I am trying to fit a quadratic to some experimental data and using polyfit in numpy. I am looking to get a concave curve, and hence want to make sure that the coefficient of the quadratic term is negative, also the fit itself is weighted, as in there are some weights on the points. Is there an easy way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of weights is described [here (numpy.polyfit)](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyfit.html). 
Basically, you need a weight vector with the same length as x and y.

To avoid the wrong sign in the coefficient, you could use a fit function definition like

```
def fitfunc(x,a,b,c):
    return -1 * abs(a) * x**2 + b * x + c
```

This will give you a negative coefficient for x**2 at all times.

Comment: @MAC your question is off topic here, I’m afraid! Rather ask it as a new question!

Comment: Sure. Posting it as new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61281011/how-to-learn-or-find-weight-vector-for-all-data-point-using-constrained-np-polyf

Answer (score 1):

You can use [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html)
.

Or you can run polyfit with rank 2 and if the last coefficient is bigger than 0. run again linear polyfit (polyfit  with rank 1)