# How to learn or find weight vector and remove outliers for all data point using Constrained np.polyfit or curve_fit?

Tags: python-3.x, exponential, scipy-optimize

I am trying to fit a `exponential decay` to some experimental data and using polyfit in numpy. Also, fit itself is weighted, that is every data point has some weight associated with it and the `polyfit function can find that optimal weights`?

Referred: [Constrained np.polyfit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26785173/constrained-np-polyfit/26884099?noredirect=1#comment108406570_26884099)

So final output would be `coefficient value` and the `weight vector` for every associated data points.

Also I want to constrain `M` parameter between 0.9 to 1 and `N` to -0.001 to -0.009

Data:

```
t(x) rate(y)
0   0.950
1   0.940
2   0.931
3   0.921
4   0.912
5   0.902
6   0.893
7   0.884
8   0.875
9   0.866
10  0.857
11  0.849
12  0.840
13  0.831
14  0.823
15  0.814
16  0.806
17  0.798
18  0.790
19  0.782
20  0.774
21  0.766
22  0.758
23  0.750
24  0.743
25  0.735
26  0.728
27  0.720
28  0.713
29  0.705
30  0.698
```

I want to fit the closest exponentialcurve to this data.

My approach:

```
    def fit_exp_linear(x, y):
            y = np.log(y)
            M, N_log = np.polyfit(t, y, 1)
            N = np.exp(N_log)
            return M, N
```

How can I  learn weight for every rows here?

Final output that I want is : `M, N and Weights vector of size dim(x)`

Outliers:

[image]
Is  there way to do it?

How to get rid of these outliers using curve_fit?

Comment: All weights are 1 by default. 

To my understanding, weights are useful to give data fewer weight that seem less reliable. But that's something that you have to give as input. Me, as a physicist, I reduce weight of obvious outliers or metrology/sensing artefacts of experimental data. On simulated data, I would choose the weight based on validity ranges of used models.

Comment: Make sense. Can't the polyfit or curve_fit could itself chose the weight?

Comment: They do! They choose 1.0! You can think of a data reliability assessment that calculates weights based on criteria you define, and later use those weights as input for the fit! There are some algorithms around how to identify outliers. They are based e.g. on general extrem value distribution concepts... But maybe that's something for the math or physics stack exchange...

Comment: @ jkalden Edited my question.

Comment: Once more: You require functions to output what they require as input. You should look for "How to identify outliers in data?", and this is rather [math](http://math.stackexchange.com) or [physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com) than coding, so maybe give it a try there.

Comment: Hi! I dont know whether you made progress. Here's a proposal: start with weights 1. Do a fit , calculate the difference from the fit for each point. Make a statistics, and for those data points being more than 3sigma out, set the weight to 0.1. Do that once more and set the weight to 0.2 for the second loop, and so on. It's a bit of a self-fulfilling prophecy, but you could give it a try!